# PDF opens when application is run locally, will not open when pushed to dev server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a grid that lists the uploaded documents for each record in another table. When I click View in the grid, while the app is on my local machine, it opens the pdf from sql server with no problem. When I push it over to the dev server and I click View, it kind of just freezes up the application for a minute or so. I'm not quite sure what's going on here, though I suspect that the method is possibly trying to run the pdf ON the server instead of my machine?

```
protected void UploadedDocumentsRadGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "ViewDoc")
    {
        if(e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            var doc = from d in db.UploadedDocuments
                      where d.ID.ToString() == item["ID"].Text
                      select d;
            foreach(var Doc in doc)
            {
                string filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".pdf"));
                filePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".pdf");
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Doc.DocumentData.ToArray());
                OpenPDFFile(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void OpenPDFFile(string filePath)
{
    using(System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        try
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Further Explanation:

This application allows users to upload scanned documents into a SQL table. If the user needs to view an uploaded document, they should be able to click on that document in the grid and that document should then open on their local machine. Am I not going about this the right way?

**UPDATE:**

Everything is working as needed now. A big thank you to Sunil for the code they provided for me. I did have to change the SQL connection to a LINQ to SQL statement, which was no big deal. The final code is below:

```
    var doc = from d in db.UploadedDocuments
              where d.ID.ToString() == Session["ID"].ToString()
              select d;
    foreach (var Doc in doc)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Doc.DocumentData.ToArray();

        this.Page.Response.Buffer = true;
        this.Page.Response.Charset = "";
        this.Page.Response.ClearContent();
        if (this.Page.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
        {
            this.Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PDF.pdf");
        }
        this.Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        this.Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        this.Page.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        this.Page.Response.Flush();
        this.Page.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Paddy you need to set the mime type from your code.

In your case, if `filePath` points to a file like `c:\myfiles\pdfs\abc.pdf` then you can use the first code snippet, but if  it the filePath is like `~/files/abc.pdf` i.e. the pdf file is stored somewhere under the website root folder then use the second code snippet. I am not sure why you would like to delete the file after it's opened in a browser.

**When filePath is an absolute or UNC path**

```
protected void OpenPDFFile(string filePath)
{
       //set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
       //write the file to  http content output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
}
```

**When filePath is an web path like ~/mypfile.pdf**

```
protected void OpenPDFFile(string filePath)
{
       //set the appropriate ContentType.
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
       //get the absolute file path
       filePath = MapPath(filePath);
       //write the file to  http content output stream.
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

From what you are saying, you want to delete files on a user's local computer from a remote web server since the web app code executes in a remote server. This is absolutely not possible, and even if it was, it would be a BIG security risk since a remote computer would then be controlling an end-user's computer. So, I suggest you follow the normal practice in a web app for streaming files to an end-user's computer.

If you have files stored in database then you could use code below to open a pdf file on end-user's computer. The end user would click on the file link in your gridview and the link click code on server-side would then execute to stream the pdf file to user's computer. Note that the link for file in your gridview should be a link button with a command argument equal to `uploadfileId` column value for that upload.

*I have assumed that in your database there is a table `Uploads` that has these columns - `UploadId, FileData, FileName, FileContentType` with UploadId being an auto-incrementing primary key.*

**Markup for Link in GridView that will download pdf when clicked**

```
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewPdfFile" runat="server" Text="View Pdf" OnClick="ViewPdfFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UploadId") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Click event for above file LinkButton in code-behind**

```
protected void ViewPdfFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {         
        int uploadId = int.Parse(btn.CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appdatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FileName, FileData, ContentType FROM Uploads WHERE UploadId=@uploadId";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uploadId", uploadId);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["FileData"];
                    contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["FileName"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
        {
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        }
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
 }
```

Comment: I didn't realize I hadn't added this part of my code, and I'm changing it right now, but I had the file being saved from the server to the end-user's Temp folder. It would then open the file, and after they were done it would delete the file from the temp folder. The reason for deleting is that they may need to open 100+ documents and I don't want to clutter their drive.

Comment: Why can you not directly stream the pdf file  from database into the user's browser instead of what you are doing now? Then the user could simply save the file on his/her computer for later analysis. This would be better and more consistent with web applications. I can provide code for this if you want.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to end up doing. Going to use the Response.WriteFile on a page, and then call that page in an iframe. Seems like the most reliable option.

Comment: No need to use an iframe. Browsers are designed to handle files being downloded from a remote website. I have explained with code in detail under `UPDATE 1` on how your scenario could be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for the help you have given me. I'm still pretty new at this, going on a year now with no previous training. Kind of a learn as I go situation, so it takes me a bit longer to understand some things. I have to lookup a lot of these classes because I don't understand what they do sometimes and I like to understand WHAT something does before I put it into play. But again, thank you for this.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask me here.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing server side code.  You may find that there are a number of open PDF's on your web server (although your generic 'catch and swallow' handling may be masking any problems there).  You need to stream the file data to your client, with the appropriate mime type.

It works locally, as your web server is the same as the machine on which you open the browser when developing.

Hard to exactly duplicate your code, as you are opening multiple PDF files - you may find it better to open these in another window rather than serving them directly on postback like this.

Comment: @Kramb The important thing is not "off site" or "on site". The difference is that System.Process only works with processes on the *local* computer, meaning the computer that is running the code. It cannot just open processes on clients connected to it. You need to develop a firm understanding of where your code is executing.